# I get an error in my asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

Markup:

```
<div class="form-bottom">
    <form role="form" action="#" method="post" class="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" for="form-username" Text="Username" CssClass="sr-only"></asp:Label>
            <%--<label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>--%>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <%--<input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">--%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
            <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I get this error:

> Control 'log_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Help me how to solve it

Comment: Do you have log_TextBox1 in your aspx Page or in master page?

Comment: You cannot have multiple forms on a page. And a Control cannot be outside that single form.

Comment: Please try adding runat=“server” to the form tag itself https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k33801s3.aspx

Comment: You must have one and only one form tag in a single form/page

Answer (score 0):

You should remove one **form tag** from your code, because asp.net page can have only one form tag

```html
<div class="form-bottom">
    <form role="form" action="#" method="post" class="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" for="form-username" Text="Username" CssClass="sr-only"></asp:Label>
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
            <br/>
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```